# Docusign Envelope ID -> email address

Tags: docusignapi

In Docusign, given an envelope Id, how can I get at some identifying info (e.g. email address) as to who originated/created/sent the document using the API only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use-case.  One way is to make the **Get Envelope Recipient Status** API call which will return status - and other metadata such as `email`, `name`, `recipientId`, etc. - for the envelope recipients:

[Get Envelope Recipient Status](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Recipient%20Status.htm)

You can also make the **Get Envelope Audit Events** API call, which will return some identifying info such as email and name and also what actions were taken:

[Get Envelope Audit Events](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Audit%20Events.htm)

Lastly, I believe the **Get Envelope Certificate** API call will probably return the most complete audit trail since it's returns the CoC (Certificate of Completion) which lists anything and everything any recipient has ever done to the envelope.  However the result of this call is a PDF (doc) so you'd have to parse that doc for specific information you're looking for.

[Get Envelope Certificate](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Certificate.htm)